# SPO - How to change default URL of list forms with custom URL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

My solution in SharePoint Hosted-Add-in.

I want to change **default** URL of NewForm.aspx with my custorm page through Visual Studio.. My custom page is in Pages/AddHoliday.html.

Can i do this directly in XML without SP destroyer(designer)?

[image]

Thank you previously!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the 3rd [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-custom-new-edit-display-form-to-list-using-sharepoint-ho/) suggested by `@SureshBolineni` and it worked! The key point is to change the deployment type of the new added page to `ElementFile`. Just Follow the guide step by step and you do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Please below post you might get the answer from those

1. Check this http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/
2. Check this http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-custom-addeditdisplay-form.html
3. check this too for SharePoint hosted APP http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-custom-new-edit-display-form-to-list-using-sharepoint-ho/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sharepoint online:

> 1. In Office 365, I created a new site (not a personal site).
> 2. I then opened the site in SharePoint Designer and imported the files into Site Pages.
> 3. I renamed index.htm to index.aspx
> 4. I right-clicked on index.aspx and set it as the home page.
>
> This works for single html page sites.
>
> For multi-page websites you will need to rename all html files to an
>   extension of aspx and change your links to point to them
>   appropriately.
>
> Edit: I have confirmed personal sites work as well.

source:
[Is there a way to host static html using Office 365 sharepoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/is-there-a-way-to-host-static-html-using-office-365-sharepoint)

Comment: I want do this operation in XML(on level add-in), because, where i deploy my add-in settings is gone..

Comment: have you tried making addholiday.html as the default page in the appmanifest file? This would work for a regular page but Im not sure for a newform. You also have to upload your html in the pages library